# How to add react-bootstrap to ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, react-bootstrap

So, I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to add react-bootstrap to it. It's already using React/ReactDOM.

I did

```
         npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

and react-bootstrap is in the node_modules folder in the project.

I added react-bootstrap to the dependencies in the Package.json file.

```
         "dependencies": {
           ......
           "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.0"
         },
```

I added react-bootstrap to the externals in the webpack.config.js file.

```
        externals:
        {
         'react-bootstrap':
           {
            "var": 'ReactBootstrap',
            web: 'ReactBootstrap',
            root: 'ReactBootStrap',
            commonjs2: 'ReactBootstrap',
            commonjs: 'ReactBootstrap',
            amd: 'ReactBoostrap'
           },
        .....
        }
```

In the Layout.cshtml, I did added a script tag with the src attribute specifying the location of the reactbootstrap.js file in node_modules folder.

```
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/node_modules/react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
```

But when I do

```
       import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
```

in the Dashboard.tsx file, it says it can't find the module.

What's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out. To add another package, TypeScript requires the addition of a declaration file. These typically carry extension of .d.ts, and define prototypes of functions, classes, interfaces, etc. within the package you are adding. In the past, these needed to be created manually, but lately npm-based packages can be handled by new Typescript. There is also a repository of commonly-used Typescript declaration files (NuGet and DefinitelyTyped)

In the package manager console in Visual Studio, you do

```
Install-Package react-bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: npm i @types/react-bootstrap --save

Comment: the output on the command line was @types/react-bootstrap@0.0.48 node_modules\@types\react-bootstrap

Comment: @typesreact/react@15.0.23